# Horizontal line in QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtextedit, qtextdocument

I'm trying to put an horizontal line in a `QTextDocument`. I'm using HTML for the formatting. To draw the line I want, I naturally used the `<hr />` tag. But the line is drawn gray and and I'd like to change its color to black.

The styles doesn't seem to apply on the `hr` element, so is there a simple workaround to have horizontal black line in my document?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want more people to see your question, add qt tag with qt4, it has 4 times more followers)

Comment: Did you try to set background-color or color property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from HTML, `<hr>` does not really have the ability to be colored or formatted. IE did it with color, Mozilla with background-color etc.
So the best (both in HTML/css and QTextDocument) is to avoid `<hr>` and take instead any very small element, size it appropriately and give it a border and a background-color of same color as the border. E.g. a table row. I can dig up some code tomorrow or the day after - I have done this before so it must be somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use some pixels height [div](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) with appropriate [background-color](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html).

Comment: `<div>` doesn't support the height attribute. So I tried using a font size of 1px, but the `div` still has a few pixels height. As a temporary(?) fix I used an image.