# QML Text with <hr> Line

Tags: html, qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to display a horizontal line in QML, with the HTML 4 subset support.
Unfortunately I fail to display the line. For instance the following code, does not display a horizontal line.
I have tried different versions of the hr-tag: `<hr>`, `<hr/>`, `<hr></hr>`. But none of them is working so far.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    Text {
        anchors.fill: parent
        textFormat: Text.RichText
        text: "Hello<hr>Hello"
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979848/horizontal-line-in-qtextedit

Answer (score 2):

It's a known bug:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-74342

You could split up your rich text blocks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Window {
    id: root

    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ColumnLayout {
        Text {
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            text: "Hello"
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.preferredHeight: 1
            color: "black"
        }
        Text {
            textFormat: Text.RichText
            text: "Hello"
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The result]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I was afraid, that this is the answer :/. The HTML string I receive is variable. Thus, I would have to break it in several strings / lines and using a ListModel + DelegateChooser. To much overhead.
But I appreciate your answer!